# Вычисляемые поля в моделях ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, yii

Как в ActiveRecord штатными средствами делать выборку с вычисляемыми полями на уровне SQL?

Например, как в запросе:

```
SELECT
    *,
    INET_NTOA(ip_addr) AS ip_addr
FROM table
```

где, поле `ip_addr` в таблице `table` хранится в формате `INT`, а через `INET_NTOA()` преобразовывается в строковое представление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем Группа условий по умолчанию смотрим  [тут](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.ar)

А вот ваше исполнение:

В класс MyClass добавляем поле:

```
        class MyClass extends CActiveRecord
     {
         public ip_addr;
    // далее ваш код

    //Также атрибут необходимо зделать несохраняемым в базу
      public function rules() 
            {
            //ваш код
            array ( 'ip_addr','unSafe')
            }
    //группа условий по умолчанию
   public function defaultScope()
    {
        return array(
            'select '=>" *, INET_NTOA(ip_addr) AS ip_addr",
        );
    }
    }
```

Если значение поля ip_addrприходит из поля от Юзера то - не нада его делать не сохраняемым. Но тогда вопрос - как вы его преобразовывайте перед сохранением? 
И еще  строку

`'select '=>" *, INET_NTOA(ip_addr) AS ip_addr",` 
нада будет переписать вот так

```
'select '=>"перечисляем все поля таблицы за исключением ip_addr, INET_NTOA(ip_addr) AS ip_addr"
```

Comment: А этот вариант работает только с несохраняемыми атрибутами?


Пробовал переопределять через `defaultScope()` реальное поле. Тоесть, после INET_NTOA ставил алиас с именем реального поля. Выводило все как положено. А, вот, сохранять не хотело.

Comment: Несохраняемым я его сделал для того чтоб его значение принудительно из формы не бралось. Не совсем понял комментарий по поводу того данного поля  - можно расписать подробней задачу?